# Javascript effect to fill the water level in a bottle dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to have an effect in javascript where the level of water in the transparent bottle increases from 0 in the bottom  to a specified amount say 800ml dynamically when user visits the page. I have seen that effect in flash but I want the amount of water to be increased can be specified by me in the admin panel

Comment: Anything is possible given enough time, money and effort. Do you mean [something like this](http://www.priteshgupta.com/2011/07/filling-a-glass-with-water-using-html5/)?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  What have you tried?  Do you have HTML you are already working with?  Do you plan to store the previous value for this user on the server or in the local browser?

Comment: Why people downvote questions which are real questions? I mean this is specific asking how to achieve some behave in javascript, I have saw several question like this in all over stackoverflow, sometimes they close the question other they don't. Man I +1 you question to put you in 0 :P. This is unfair IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

Start with a reverse image of the bottle (inside is the transparent portion), then behind it have an element with variable height that contains your background.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, of course. Put it in a div (you'll have to fit it to the size of the bottle somehow), color it blue, and then use something like the jQuery `animate()` function to extend the height, giving the effect that the bottle is filling up.

If you want the "increased height" to be controllable, just have jQuery pull in the needed height from wherever you store your admin settings.

Comment: thanks do you know any good tutorial site from where I can have a look at that. As I am new to javascript

Comment: Time to crack open a good Javascript book.  Some HTML5 and CSS would also help.

Comment: @Rajan I'm gonna recommend [w3schools](http://www.ww3schools.com) even though lots of people don't like it (it has had a few mistakes on it in the past). I like the javascript tutorial on there, though.